# Copy build artifacts from insider docker to host

Tags: docker, jenkins, copy, cp

This is my jenkinsfile:

```
   pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                echo '####################################################
                echo 'Building Docker container'
                echo '####################################################

                script {
                    sh 'docker build -t my-gcc:1.0 .'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Run') { 
            steps {
                echo '##########################################################
                echo 'Running Docker Image'
                echo '##########################################################
                script {
                    sh 'docker run  --privileged -i my-gcc:1.0'
                    sh 'docker cp my-gcc:1.0:/usr/src/myCppProject/build/*.hex .'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Program') { 
            steps {
                echo '#######################################################
                echo 'Programming target '
                echo '#######################################################

                script {
                    sh 'openocd -d0 -f board/st_nucleo_f4.cfg -c "init;targets;halt;flash write_image erase Testbench.hex;shutdown"'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the docker image is build and then run, after this I would like to extract the hex file form the container to the jenkins working directory so that I can flash it to the board.
But when I try to copy the file I get this error:

```
+ docker cp my-gcc:1.0:1.0:/usr/src/myCppProject/build/*.hex .
Error: No such container:path: my-gcc:1.0:1.0:/usr/src/myCppProject/build/*.hex
```

I tried to access other folders in the container and copy the content, but always the same error. This way it seems that I cannot access any folder or file in the container.

What am I doing wrong?

Regards
Martin

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins has some standard support for Docker; this is described in [Using Docker with Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) in the Jenkins documentation.  In particular, Jenkins knows how to use a Docker image that contains just tools, combined with the project's workspace directory.  I'd use that support instead of trying to script `docker cp`.

That might look roughly like so:

```groovy
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      // Jenkins will run `docker build` for you
      agent { dockerfile { args '--privileged' } }
      steps {
        // The current working directory is bind-mounted into the container;
        // the image's `ENTRYPOINT`/`CMD` is ignored.
        // Copy the file out of the container:
        sh "cp /usr/src/myCppProject/build/*.hex ."
      }
    }
    stage('Program') {
      agent any // so not in Docker
      steps {
        sh 'openocd -d0 -f board/st_nucleo_f4.cfg -c "init;targets;halt;flash write_image erase Testbench.hex;shutdown"'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you use this approach, also consider whether you should run the main build sequence via Jenkins pipeline steps, or a `sh` invocation that runs a shell script, or a Makefile, or if a Dockerfile is actually right.  It might make sense to build a Docker image out of your customized compiler, but then use the Jenkins pipeline support to build the image for the target board rather than trying to do it all in a Dockerfile.

In the invocation you show, you can't directly `docker cp` a file out of an image.  When you start the container, use `docker run --name` to give it a name, then `docker cp` from that container name.

```
sh 'docker run --name builder ... my-gcc:1.0'
sh 'docker cp builder:/usr/src/myCppProject/build/*.hex .'
sh 'docker rm builder'
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks a lot for your response. I see, to use the integrated support for docker seems to be a more elegant way. Bit just for that sake of curiosity:

sh 'docker run --name builder ... my-gcc:1.0'
sh 'docker cp builder:/usr/src/myCppProject/build/*.hex .'
sh 'docker rm builder'

should work?

Comment: The first approach works like a charm! :-) The second one (similar to my original) still doesn't work and ends with the same error. Regarding your question about the build process, I do use bitbuckets which triggers a Jenkins pipeline at each push. So I thought that the Jenkinsfile that triggers a docker that builds everything is more or less the only option. Are there others?